# How get and edit message by ID in discord.net?

Tags: discord, discord.net

To get channel I use

```
Client.GetChannel(Bot.ChannelStatisticsID)
```

To get message I use

```
Channel.GetMessageAsync(Bot.MessageStatisticsID)
```

How edit message?

Comment: Simply call [ModifyAsync](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketUserMessage.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketUserMessage_ModifyAsync_System_Action_Discord_MessageProperties__Discord_RequestOptions_) on the message object

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your channel you can try this:

```
await Channel.ModifyMessageAsync(YourMessageID, m => m.Content = "YourNewContent");
```

Remember that bot can only edit its own messages.